# HTML response to DGV cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, httpwebrequest

In my app, I place several HTTP web requests in order to validate credentials for users on my site. Each request is broke down and sent to a DataGridView table with 3 columns = User, Pass, and response. Depending on the response the same credentials may need to be retried with a new proxy and response updated.

My question is how do I place several HTTP requests at the same time, say 20 and record each on a DGV and monitor the response in case I need to swap the proxy out and run it again.

Here is how I am posting and getting the response.

```
Function Post(ByVal Data As String, ByVal Proxy As String)
    Dim responseData As String = ""
    Dim Site As String = "example.com"
    Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(Site)
    Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
    Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding()
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(Data)
    Try
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36"
        request.Accept = "*/*"
        request.CookieContainer = tempCookies
        request.ContentLength = byteData.Length
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
        request.KeepAlive = True
        request.Timeout = 60000
        request.Method = "POST"
        If request.Method = "POST" Then
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            Dim postByteArray() As Byte = encoding.GetBytes(Data)
            request.ContentLength = postByteArray.Length
            Dim postStream As IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            postStream.Write(postByteArray, 0, postByteArray.Length)
            postStream.Close()
        End If
        Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        If response.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            Dim responseStream As IO.StreamReader = _
              New IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            responseData = responseStream.ReadToEnd()
        End If
        response.Close()
    Catch e As Exception
        responseData = "An error occurred: " & e.Message
    End Try
    Post = responseData
End Function

 Dim comboResp As String = (Post("Username=" & User + "&Password=" & Pass & "&submitLogin=Log+In&ReturnUrl=", rndProxy))
    Dim row As String() = New String() {User, Pass, comboResp}
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
```

I cannot seem to get the response to show in the cell to start, then have no clue how to call a sub depending on the response of each row.

Closest example of what I am after would be Sentry MBA.

Comment: This procedure won't work neither in Basic nor in Web Form authentication. Basic auth requires `HttpWebRequest.Credentials` header to specify Base64 encoded credentials. Web Form auth requires the names of the form <input >elements, plus, eventually, __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATON, to be passed in URL encoded format. + You don't need a CookieContainer for testing. `.AllowAutoRedirect` has to be set to false, so `.KeepAlive`

Comment: I am sure there is unused clutter, but I can log in and get the source code from URL after redirect on valid credentials. I'm looking for a way to monitor the response in a cell for 25+ cells.

Comment: You are trying to authenticate through a Web Form LogIn page. In this case, when the request fails, the resulting StatusCode is always StatusCode.OK and the response is the original (redirected) html page. Verify its content before anything else.

Comment: I use a try catch to verify response type with unique HTML for validity. I did not share that. I can't figure out how to update the cell according to that specific threads web response. Or launch multiple threads for now.

Comment: A Try/Catch block won't catch anything, since no WebException or System.Exception is thrown. Indulge me, check the content of your response and verify if that represents the Landingpage or the Loginpage. BTW, the StatusCode after a successful LogIn must be "302". I have no problem giving you the answer you seek, but first, clear the groung.

Comment: comboResp = Post("Username=" & TextBox1.Text + "&Password=" & TextBox2.Text & "&submitLogin=Log+In&ReturnUrl=", rndProxy)
           (Webpage specific login pattern) ComboResp contains the redirected pages HTML source. Then I check the source for keywords only found in successful or failed logins. I do not check the actuall status code, although I will look into that also.

Comment: The only way this could be working for you is that you're not using a standard WebForm authentication procedure. So you server-side script processes a request using a non-standard pattern. In this scenario, any server response meaning is to be considered _custom_ (ie. unreliable). Is this the case?. You understand that adjusting an answer on unknown parameters in quite improbable. In a standard scenario, after posting the Login parameters, you wait for a standard "302" response and follow the redirection to the final Landingpage through 1 or more hops. If Not Standard => Who knows.

Comment: I'm posting a possible solution, see if you can make it work. Comment under it if you have questions (it's a bit long).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you start your process from an Button.Click event handler:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text

Const COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION As Long = &H80131509
'A class used to contain all requests data
Private _AuthenticationObject As AuthObject
'A List of UserIds as Passwords KeyValue pairs
Private _CredentialsList As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Private Async Sub btnTestLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTestLogin.Click
    btnTestLogin.Enabled = False
    'Fill a list of credentials (the use of a Dictionary is just one possible method)
    _CredentialsList.Add("Username1", "Password1")
    _CredentialsList.Add("Username2", "Password2")
    _CredentialsList.Add("Username3", "Password3")

    _AuthenticationObject = New AuthObject
    _AuthenticationObject.URL = "http://somesite.com"

    _AuthenticationObject.ProxyParameters.Host = "somehostaddress"
    _AuthenticationObject.ProxyParameters.Port = 8080
    'Or simple proxy URI
    '_AuthenticationObject.ProxyParameters.Uri = New Uri("http://someproxyhost")
    _AuthenticationObject.ProxyParameters.BypassLocal = False
    _AuthenticationObject.ProxyParameters.Credentials = New String() {"proxyuserid", "proxypassword"}

    'If you don't want to use an Async starter, use this
    'And of course => For Each _item In _result.Result
    'Dim _result As Task(Of List(Of String())) = Task.Run(Function() CheckAuthentication(_AuthenticationObject, True))
    'Task.WaitAny(_result)

    Dim _result As List(Of String()) = Await CheckAuthentication(_AuthenticationObject, False)

    For Each _item In _result
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(_item)
    Next

    btnTestLogin.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

This is a gateway function used to coordinate the sequential requests:

```
Public Async Function CheckAuthentication(ByVal _AuthenticationObject As AuthObject, ByVal _useproxy As Boolean) As Task(Of List(Of String()))
    Dim _authresult As List(Of String()) = New List(Of String())

    _AuthenticationObject.UseProxy = _useproxy

    For Each _item In _CredentialsList
        _AuthenticationObject.LogInData = "Username=" & _item.Key & "&Password=" & _item.Value & "&submitLogin=Log+In&ReturnUrl="

        'This an Async version of you original function, plus some editing
        '_AuthenticationObject = Await PostAsync(_AuthenticationObject)

        'Test it first using a delay
        Await Task.Delay(1000)

        _authresult.Add(New String() {_item.Key,
                                      _item.Value,
                                      If(_AuthenticationObject.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK", "Failed"),
                                      If(_AuthenticationObject.UseProxy = True, "Proxy", "No Proxy")})
    Next
    Return _authresult
End Function
```

This is your original function edited to support a more complex authentication object

```
Private Async Function PostAsync(ByVal _PostData As AuthObject) As Task(Of AuthObject)

    Dim httpRequest As HttpWebRequest
    Dim _StatusCode As HttpStatusCode
    Dim _Payload As String = String.Empty
    Dim _postparameters As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_PostData.LogInData)

    Try
        httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(_PostData.URL)
        httpRequest.Timeout = 10000
        httpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = False
        httpRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = False
        httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
        httpRequest.Accept = "ext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
        httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate;q=0.8")

        httpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        httpRequest.ContentLength = _postparameters.Length

        If _PostData.UseProxy Then
            If Not IsNothing(_PostData.ProxyParameters) Then
                If (_PostData.ProxyParameters.Host.Length > 0) Then
                    httpRequest.Proxy = New WebProxy(_PostData.ProxyParameters.Host, _PostData.ProxyParameters.Port)
                Else
                    httpRequest.Proxy = New WebProxy(_PostData.ProxyParameters.Uri, _PostData.ProxyParameters.BypassLocal)
                End If
                httpRequest.Proxy.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(_PostData.ProxyParameters.Credentials(0), _
                                                                                        _PostData.ProxyParameters.Credentials(1))
            Else
                httpRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()
            End If
        End If

        Using _stream As Stream = Await httpRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync()
            _stream.Write(_postparameters, 0, _postparameters.Length)
        End Using

        Using httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(Await httpRequest.GetResponseAsync(), HttpWebResponse)
            Dim _encoding As System.Text.Encoding

            _encoding = If(httpResponse.CharacterSet.Length > 0, 
                           Encoding.GetEncoding(httpResponse.CharacterSet), 
                           Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"))

            Using _stream As Stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream()
                _stream.Position = 0
                Using _reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(_stream, _encoding)
                    _Payload = _reader.ReadToEnd().Trim()
                End Using
            End Using
            _StatusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode
        End Using

    Catch exW As WebException
        If Not IsNothing(exW.Response) Then
            _StatusCode = CType(exW.Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode
        End If
        _Payload = String.Empty
    Catch exS As System.Exception
        _StatusCode = If(exS.HResult = COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION,
                         CType(WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure, HttpStatusCode),
                         CType(WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled, HttpStatusCode))
        _Payload = String.Empty
    End Try

    _PostData.StatusCode = _StatusCode
    _PostData.PayLoad = _Payload

    Return _PostData

End Function
```

These are the Class Objects used:

```
Public Class AuthObject

    Private _URL As String = String.Empty
    Private _LogInData As String = String.Empty
    Private _UseProxy As Boolean = False
    Private _ProxyParameters As ProxyParameters
    Private _PayLoad As String = String.Empty
    Private _StatusCode As HttpStatusCode

    Public Sub New()
        Me._ProxyParameters = New ProxyParameters
    End Sub

    Public Property URL() As String
        Get
            Return Me._URL
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._URL = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LogInData() As String
        Get
            Return Me._LogInData
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._LogInData = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property UseProxy() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me._UseProxy
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me._UseProxy = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ProxyParameters() As ProxyParameters
        Get
            Return Me._ProxyParameters
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ProxyParameters)
            Me._ProxyParameters = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PayLoad() As String
        Get
            Return Me._PayLoad
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._PayLoad = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property StatusCode() As HttpStatusCode
        Get
            Return Me._StatusCode
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As HttpStatusCode)
            Me._StatusCode = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class ProxyParameters

    Private _Uri As Uri
    Private _Host As String
    Private _Port As Integer
    Private _Credentials As String()
    Private _BypassLocal As Boolean

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Property Uri() As Uri
        Get
            Return Me._Uri
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Uri)
            Me._Uri = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Host() As String
        Get
            Return Me._Host
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._Host = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Port() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._Port
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Me._Port = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Credentials() As String()
        Get
            Return Me._Credentials
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String())
            Me._Credentials = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property BypassLocal() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me._BypassLocal
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me._BypassLocal = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```